# Question about Hardline Pro Challenge

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I'm trying to unlock the Hardline Pro perk, but one of the challenges is not very clear. It says:

> Earn 7 killstreaks in one match while using hardline.

Does that mean I have to get 2+ kills in a row seven times (meaning it's more advantageous to die immediately after the second kill), or does it mean I have to earn 7 kill streak rewards (meaning it's more advantageous to purchase cheap rewards and try to stay alive)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did that task last night on Domination Nuke Town.
You should be able to do it in one game without dying on purpose
Ensure you have your first perk set to three kills and using hardline if you get 2 kills before you die seven times it will be completed.

Good Luck

Comment: Nice hint. Domination Nuketown did the trick for me too.